# Use Zend Framework in non-rewriting mode?

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-rewriting

currently `$ctrl->view->url()` keeps building urls like this:

```
http://host.com/user/profile/123
```

but I want it to be like this:

```
http://host.com/index.php?controller=user&action=profile&id=123
```

And I hope Zend can recognize all these Params by `$ctrl->request()->getParam()`

Is there any way to do it? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you want to do that?

Comment: this web is not to display a website content, but to receive lots of long params from an mobile app. "&key=value" is the easiest way for mobile developer:)

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can keep the rewrite and still attach such params in the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build an URL like that you do not need a view helper, do you? ;)

My guess it you need this for the params, so here's  what i think will help you

```
//view.phtml
$this->url(array(
  'controller'=>'user',
  'action'=>'profile',
  'id'=>'123'
));
```

The above will output `http://www.name.tld/user/profile/id/123` which is equivalent to the link given above.